# Django: get duplicates based on annotation

Tags: python, django, duplicates, django-annotate

I want to get all duplicates based on a *case insensitive field value*.

Basically to rewrite this SQL query

```
SELECT count(*), lower(name)
FROM manufacturer
GROUP BY lower(name)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

with Django ORM. I was hoping something like this would do the trick

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

from myapp.models import Manufacturer


qs = Manufacturer.objects.annotate(
    name_lower=Lower('name'),
    cnt=Count('name_lower')
).filter('cnt__gt'=1)
```

but of course it didn't work.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Manufacturer.objects.values(name).annotate(
    cnt=Count('name_lower')
).filter('cnt__gt'=1)

Comment: @SergAnuke that will not work as `name_lower` isn't an actual column but comes from annotation

Comment: .annotate(name_lower=Lower('name')) 
.values('name_lower')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try it:

```
qs = Manufacturer.objects.annotate(lname=Lower('name')
     ).values('lname').annotate(cnt=Count(Lower('name'))
     ).values('lname', 'cnt').filter(cnt__gt=1).order_by('lname', 'cnt')
```

why should add the `order_by` [ordering-or-order-by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by):

the sql query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    LOWER("products_manufacturer"."name") AS "lname",
    COUNT(LOWER("products_manufacturer"."name")) AS "cnt"
FROM "products_manufacturer"
GROUP BY LOWER("products_manufacturer"."name")
HAVING COUNT(LOWER("products_manufacturer"."name")) > 1
ORDER BY "lname" ASC, "cnt" ASC
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Though, it doesn't work if `order_by('lname', 'cnt')` isn't part of the query. Do you know why? Also, `annotate(cnt=Count(Lower('name'))` can be simplified to `annotate(cnt=Count('lname')`.

Comment: Order in which `annotate()` and `values()` clauses are applied to a query is significant: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses